# Solve equation $ 1+2^x=3^y$

Tags: diophantine-equations

Find integers $x$ and $y$ such that$$ 1+2^x=3^y.$$
It is obvious that $x = y = 1$ and $x = 3, y = 2$ are solutions.
I think others are not. 
How to show that?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Case 1: $y$ is odd.  Then $3^y \equiv 3 \mod 8$.  When is $2^x \equiv 2 \mod 8$?

Case 2: $y = 2 z$ is even.  Then $2^x = 3^{2z} - 1 = (3^z - 1)(3^z + 1)$, so 
$3^z - 1$ and $3^z + 1$ are powers of $2$.  What powers of $2$ differ by $2$?

By the way, this proof of a special case of Catalan's conjecture dates back to Gersonides (Levi ben Gershon) in 1343.

Comment: This is excellent. (+1)

Comment: good old Levi ben Gershon and induction, wonder how many people ever realise that?

Answer (score 10):

Clearly in this case Robert Israel's very elegant solution is perfect, but it is worth noting that what we have here is a special case of [Catalan's conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture) (now a theorem, proved by [Preda Mihăilescu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preda_Mih%C4%83ilescu)) which states that the only solution of

$$x^a - y^b = 1$$ in integers (greater than 1) is given by $3^2-2^3 = 1$, so you are correct, there are no other solutions.

Comment: I do not like this answer because it uses a very difficult (and recently proved) theorem to prove a result that has a much more elementary proof.