# Find $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that : $\frac{a^{2}-2}{ab+2}\in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

> $1$. Find $a;b\in \mathbb{Z}^+$ such that : $\frac{a^{2}-2}{ab+2}\in \mathbb{Z}$
>
> $2$. Find $m;n>1$ such that : $2^m+3^n=k^2$ $(k\in \mathbb{Z})$

Problem 1. I thought :

$\frac{a^{2}-2}{ab+2}\in \mathbb{Z}\Rightarrow a^{2}-2\vdots ab+2\Rightarrow a^{2}+ab\vdots ab+2\Rightarrow ab(a+b)\vdots ab+2\Rightarrow 2(a+b)\vdots ab+2$

But i don't know how to do next!!

Comment: Typically, when someone posts just "Prove $X$", it is considered rude. People don't want to do other people's homework, so posters should show that they've at least put some effort into the problem. What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 2):

**1**

Case 1 : $\frac{a^2-2}{ab+2} =0$ no solution

Case 2 : $\frac{a^2-2}{ab+2} >0 $ and $a < b$ : So $$
\frac{a^2-2}{ab+2} < 1$$

no solution.

Case 3 : $\frac{a^2-2}{ab+2} >0 $ and $a \geq b\ (a>1,\ a>b)$ : So $$
\frac{a^2-2}{ab+2} < \frac{a^2}{ab} = \frac{a}{b},\ ba^2-2b < a^2b +2a$$
So $$ ab\leq ab(a-b)< 2(a+b),\ (a-2)(b-2)< 4$$

Hence if $b \geq 3$, then $a\leq 5$. In this case by computation we have $(a,b)=(4,3)$ (There was a solution-finding of questioner)

Case 4 : $\frac{a^2-2}{ab+2} <0 $ : no solution.

Comment: $a=4;b=3$ then $\frac{a^2-2}{ab+2}=1$ !?

Comment: Thank you. I made a mistake in calculation

Answer (score 1):

$2^m+3^n=k^2$

$m$ must be even,otherwise remainder of $2^m$ divided by $3$ will be $2$ thus $k^2=3w+2$ that is impossible.

$m=2t$

$3^n=k^2-2^{2t}=(k-2^t)(k+2^t)$

So

$k-2^t=3^a,k+2^t=3^b$

Then we will have:
$2.2^t=3^b-3^a \to 2^{t+1}=3^a(3^{b-a}-1)\to a=0,3^{b}-1=2^{t+1} \to b\in\{1,2\}$
So
$t\in\{0,2\} \to k\in\{4,5\}\to (m,n)\in\{(0,1),(4,2)\}$

But $m,n>1$ so $(m,n)=4,2$.

To know why $3^b-1=2^{t+1}$ has only two answers, look at [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579701/solve-equation-12x-3y).

Answer (score 1):

**2**

We note that $(m,n) = (4,2)$ is a solution , we guess that it is the only one.Note that $3$ doesn't divide $k$, and hence $k^2 \equiv 1\pmod{3} $.

**Case 1:** If $m$ is odd we can deduce from Fermat's little theorem that $$ 1 \equiv k^2 \equiv 2^m + 3^n \equiv 2^{2s+1} +0 \equiv 2 \pmod{3} $$

, which is a contradiction.

**Case 2:** If m is even, we let $m=2s$ with $s > 0$, we can then write the equation as $$3^n = k^2 - 2^{2s} = (k - 2^s)(k + 2^s)$$, We note that $ \gcd ((k -2^s),(k + 2^s )) | 2^{s+1} $, so $3$ cannot divide both factors, thus if we have a solution we must have $k - 2^s = 1$ which implies $k = 2^s + 1 $, so it suffices to solve $$3^n - 1 = 2^{s+1}$$ (Which seems a little easier at least we have only two unknowns).

There is a known theorem (and technique) known as "Lifting exponent lemma" you can read this [article](https://www.awesomemath.org/wp-content/uploads/reflections/2007_3/Lifting_the_exponent.pdf) , which say that (denoting $v_p(n)$ to be the largest exponent of $p$ dividing n ) if $a \equiv b \pmod{2}$ , and $v_2(\frac{a^2-b^2}{2}) = \alpha $ , $v_2(x)= \beta$ , then $v_2(a^x - b^x) = \alpha + \beta $ (in fact that theorem arises naturally in practice in special cases )

So in our equation in order to have a solution we must have $v_2(3^n-1)=s+1$ , but $v_2(\frac{3^2 - 1}{2}) = 2 $ , thus $v_2(n) = s-1 > 0 $ (since $n > 1$), We have

- If $n=2$, then $s=2$ is a solution , which corresponds to $m=4$
- If $n>2$, we must have $2^{s-1} \| n $ , if $s=2$ , then $s=2m$ , with $m > 1$ , but then it is clearly not solution. If $s > 2$ , then by induction one can prove that $$2^{s+1} < 3^{2^{s-1}} - 1 < 3^{2^{s-1}f} - 1 $$, when $f > 1$ .

So the only solution is that we have got.