# Number of integer solutions of a nonlinear equations of the form $2^m-3^k=y$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

Given a fixed odd integer $y\in\mathbb{Z}$ and a natural number $n\in\mathbb{N}$, can we compute the cardinality of the set $\{(m,k)\in\mathbb{N}^2:k\leq n, 2^m-3^k=y\}$ explicitly?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Note (as in the solution to problem 1404, here: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2690747) that any $y > 8$ that is not congruent to either $5$ or $7$ mod $8$ can be immediately ruled out.

Comment: Probably not..see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579701/solve-equation-12x-3y) for the case $y=1$.